# MySQL Join 3 Tables Together

Tags: mysql, join

Hi i have following tables

users (id is primary key/auto increment)

```
    id    |    alias    |    name
----------------------------------
1         |Joe          |Joe Anderson
2         |TG           |Tegu Kuan
3         |Peter        |Peter Neil
4         |Nicol        |Clin Nicol
```

images (id is primary key/auto increment. images.user represents users.id)

```
    id    |    image    |    user
----------------------------------
1         |125.jpg      |1
2         |126.jpg      |1
3         |127.jpg      |2
4         |128.jpg      |3
```

feed (id is primary key/auto increment. feed.user represents users.id)

```
    id    |    title    |    user
----------------------------------
1         |-some text a-|1
2         |-some text b-|2
3         |-some text c-|3
4         |-some text d-|3
```

I want to join these 3 tables in following conditions

1. Output should contains users.alias, images.image, feed.title
2. Four rows as feed table have four rows (I need to SELECT FROM `feed`).
3. Only the last image of same user. as example 126.jpg for user 1 not 125.jpg
4. Descending order of feed.id

Output should be like this

```
   alias  |    image    |    title
----------------------------------
Peter     |128.jpg      |-some text d-
Peter     |128.jpg      |-some text c-
TG        |127.jpg      |-some text b-
Joe       |126.jpg      |-some text a-
```

Please help me to write this query.

Comment: Are you even going to attempt it yourself? To be fair, your tables are simple and therefore the query is pretty simple. Any basic JOIN tutorial would give you enough information to do this.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far so that we can help correct where you are having problems?

Comment: @Lee I've tried many times. I think i have problem of my knowledge about mysql join. it's easy to me if there are two tables. that's why i took about 15 mins to write these all table in this post.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do and why it didn't work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that neither the images nor the feed table has a good notion for "last" beyond the order you show.  I don't see how you can decide which one is in force for a given user in a general way.

Your user 1 has images 125.jpg and 126.jpg.  Do you plan to keep that scheme?  What happens if you insert an image named "some-random-image.jpg"?  What is its order relative to the two you have in force now?

It's a trivial problem if both the image and title have a timestamp to indicate effective date.  If that were true, you could select each one on the basis of latest effective date.

In that case you can write a SELECT with two JOINs and a couple of subselects to choose the effective date for the given date.

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT U.ID, U.ALIAS, I.IMAGE, F.TITLE
FROM USERS AS U
JOIN IMAGES AS I 
ON U.ID = I.USER
JOIN FEED AS F
ON U.ID = F.USER
GROUP BY U,ID
```

Add WHERE clauses to choose "latest" as needed.

Comment: @Mike Brant, Here what I already done. I still have to fix the last image of user should show in the output. This only show first image in the table.

    SELECT feeds.id, users.alias, images.image
    FROM feeds
    INNER JOIN users
    ON feeds.user=users.id
    INNER JOIN images
    ON feeds.user=images.user
    GROUP BY feeds.id
    ORDER BY feeds.id DESC